# Why is my for loop printing memory location

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, memory, printing

I've have a for loop which is prints the difference in sets. The compact version prints the memory location while the generic works as it should. it's not the biggest issue but would like to know why this is happening and if there is something i can do to work around it.

```
M = set(map(int, "2 4 5 9".split()))

N = set(map(int, "2 4 11 12".split()))
      

print(i for i in sorted(list(M.difference(N))+ list(N.difference(M))))
```

Output

```
   <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f10569c03c0>
```

Working Solution

```
for i in sorted(list(M.difference(N))+ list(N.difference(M))):
    print(i)
```

Desired Output

```
5

9

11

12
```

Comment: That is not a "compact for loop". That is a generator expression. You shouldn't think of list comprehensions, generator expressions etc as "compact for-loops". That isn't what they are

Comment: Can you [edit] to show the exact output of the two versions of the code?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you ill take that on board. Just out of curiosity what would be a 'compact for loop' if anything. I done a quick search and can only find 'list comprehension'

Comment: There isn't any. A for-loop is compact enough